# Can this Diophantine equation be solved? $33x+14y=115$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can this Diophantine equation be solved?
$33x+14y=115$

I got the gcd $(33,14)$ to equal $1$ and since $1|15$ the equation can be solved. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct!

Answer (score 3):

A little bit depends on whether you want to solve the equation for *integers* $x$ and $y$ or for *nonnegative* integers $x$ and $y$.  In the former case, then yes, showing that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $c$ is enough to show that $ax+by=c$ has integer solutions; when $\gcd(a,b)=1$, it's hardly necessary to note that $1|c$.  (A small typo:  the OP wrote $1|15$ instead of $1|115$.)  In the latter case, there's more work to be done.  And for this problem, $33x+14y=115$ does *not* have any nonnegative integer solutions.  (If it did, $x$ would have to be either $1$ or $3$, but $14$ does not divide either $82$ or $16$.)

Answer (score 0):

33x + 14y = 115 is equivalent to 33x = 115(mod 14). Solving x = 9(mod 14) and x = 9 + 14k. Substituting x = 9 + 14k into the original equation, you get y = -13 - 33k. The complete solution is x = 9 + 14k and y = -13 - 33k.